# Python "ModuleNotFound" error when running from CLI but not when running from Pycharm after `pip install -e ." (using Anaconda)

Tags: python

tldr: I can run my script from Pycharm, but not the command line. The module was installed in Anaconda by `pip install -e .` (my module shows up in my packages when using `conda list`). The module directory is found on `sys.path` when I run it from both Pycharm and Command line, however `PYTHONPATH` contains my module path when I run it from Pycharm but not CLI. I'm trying to avoid going the hack route and adding my script to `PYTHONPATH`.

**Longer version**

I have a python project with a directory structure like below:

```
project1/
    mycode/
    __init__.py
        code/
        __init__.py
        simulation/
            __init__.py
            print_path.py
```

where I am trying to run `python print_path.py` from the command line however it is not running and throws an exception about ModuleNotFound error. The strange thing is when I run this from PyCharm I get the expected behavior and it runs. I am using Anaconda3 and python3.7. I installed my code as a packaged module via pip by running `pip install -e .`

Path of `print_path.py`: 
`C:\Users\axk\Documents\Work\project1\my_code\code\simulation`

I've checked that my package is in my environment packages by viewing `conda list` where I see my package there.

Here is the contents of `print_path.py`

```
import os
import sys

try:
    print("Attempting to print paths")
    print()
    user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
    print(user_paths)
except KeyError as e:
    print("there was an error: {}".format(e))
    user_paths = []

try:
    print()
    print("SYS.PATH")
    for path in sys.path:
        print(path)
except KeyError as e:
    print("there was an error: {}".format(e))

import code.simulation
print("made it past import")
print(code.simulation.__file__)
```

This prints the contents of sys.path and also what is on `PYTHONPATH`

When running from pycharm the following is my output:

```
Attempting to print paths

['C:\\Users\\axk\\Documents\\Work\\project1\\my_code',
 'C:\\Users\\axk\\Documents\\Work\\project1\\my_code\\code']

SYS.PATH
C:\Users\axk\Documents\Work\project1\my_code\code\simulation
C:\Users\axk\Documents\Work\project1\my_code
C:\Users\axk\Documents\Work\project1\my_code\code
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\python37.zip
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\DLLs
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\lib
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
made it past import
C:\Users\axk\Documents\Work\project1\my_code\code\simulation\__init__.py
```

When I run it from the command line `python print_path.py` I get

```
Attempting to print paths

there was an error: 'PYTHONPATH'

SYS.PATH
C:\Users\axk\Documents\Work\project1\my_code\code\simulation
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\python37.zip
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\DLLs
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\lib
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\lib\site-packages
c:\users\axk\documents\work\project1\my_code
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\axk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_code\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "print_path.py", line 21, in <module>
    import code.simulation
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.simulation'; 'code' is not a package
```

What doesn't make any sense is that says when I import my file it is found in `C:\Users\axk\Documents\Work\project1\my_code\code\simulation\__init__.py` . And this path exists on `sys.path` when I run it from Pycharm and the command line.

The only way I've gotten it to work from the command line is by hackily adding the script to PYTHONPATH. However from the python documentation, it should find it as it's supposed to check sys.path for the packages. So why doesn't this work?

---

### Edit

Ok here is something strange. If I do `from code import *` the code proceeds. Not sure why that's happening because each module has an `__init__.py` file

Comment: Are you activating the environment correctly before running it from the command line? _The module was installed in Anaconda by pip install -e . (my module shows up in my packages when using conda list)._ If you're using Conda, why package your code with pip?

Comment: yes I've made sure I've activated my environment before running the script from CLI. Good question I didn't know that I could do the same with `conda develop` for my package. I tried both and I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: _the same issue._ The same _ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.simulation'; 'code' is not a package_ ?

Comment: Yes that is the error when I run the script

Comment: Did you try in it in a fresh environment?

Comment: yes I just tried it from a fresh environment and I'm still getting the same "module not found" error

Comment: ok here is something strange. If I do `from code import *` the code proceeds. Not sure why that's happening because each module has an `__init__.py` file

Comment: Beware: PyCharm modifies the `sys.path`. It automatically adds everything you mark as "content root" to it.

Comment: ok got it. I just turned that setting off in the run configuration I unchecked `Add content roots to PYTHONPATH` and pycharm now throws the same error. So is this something I'm doing wrong with my packaging? I don't want to have to modify `PYTHONPATH` that is not a good practice.

Comment: What I think is confusing is when I print out `pip freeze` and check my packages in PyCharm (under project interpreter) I see my package `code` installed there. However, my script runs and says `code is not a package` ?